# Xsl How to call the function SelectAll() without onclick event, every loop in the for each tag?

Tags: html, xslt

How to call the function SelectAll() without onclick event?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAll() {
      var x = 0;
      for(var cnt=0; cnt<100; cnt++) {
        x = cnt; // whatever
      }
      alert(x);
    }
  </script>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <div onclick="SelectAll()">Click!</div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `alert` is not a function a JavaScript engine implements, instead it is exposed by browsers to JavaScript. Of course, in HTML, whether created by XSLT or written any other way, if you want to call the `SelectAll` function declared in a previous script block, you can just use `<script>SelectAll();</script>`, but it will be the browser executing that script while rendering the HTML with the script, not any XSLT processor.

Comment: but it will happened jast once, not in every loop in for each, no? @MartinHonnen

Comment: If your XSLT creates e.g. ten `<script>SelectAll();</script>` elements, for instance, by having an `xsl:for-each` processing e.g. ten items and producing a `script` element for each item, then the browser will call the `SelectAll` function ten times. Not sure if you get away these days to try to use `alert()` dialogs that many times, but the whole issue is that you seem to expect the XSLT processor to process the script while it is the browser doing it.

Comment: ohh ok, sorry I didnt get you before, thanks!!

Comment: One problem in need to path a parameter from the xsl file to the function, for example "title" but if I do `<script>SelectAll();</script>`  I cant path inside the "title" parameter like `<script>SelectAll("parameter");</script>` , any idea what can I do? @MartinHonnen

Comment: Is `title` the XPath expression on the XSLT side? You can construct a JavaScript string with e.g. ``<script>SelectAll(`<xsl:value-of select="title"/>`);</script>``. I have used backticks (not supported by IE) as the JavaScript string literal delimiter as they are most unlikely to appear in the title data, of course you can use `<script>SelectAll('<xsl:value-of select="title"/>');</script>`, it all comes down to whether your data can contain the delimiter and how robust you need that approach to be, for a general purpose library you would need to make sure to escape the delimiter in title.